# Is it possible to add a network drive to %PATH% environment variable

Tags: python, windows, sysinternals

I have a python script calling an exe file. The exe file can be in the same folder as that of the python script or in a network drive. Is it possible to call the exe if it is in a remote drive/computer? Can this be done by setting the %PATH% variable

Comment: When you tried it, what happened?

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can put a UNC path in your `%PATH%` env variable, and it will work if you have access to that path with your current session.

Answer (score 3):

Although use of a UNC will often work in the %PATH% variable this is unsupported by Microsoft as it can cause problems such as service failures.  This issue continues through Windows 7 / Server 2008R2.

Please reference [Microsoft KB Article ID: 978856](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/978856)

*cheers